# Ckeditor with webpack do not work

Tags: npm, ckeditor, webpack

Is there a way to get work it ckeditor with webpack?

**installed as:**

```
npm install ckeditor --save-dev
```

**included**

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '../../node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor';
require('ckeditor')
```

**getting**

```
ckeditor:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this inside index.html

```
  <script>
      var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/ckeditor/';
  </script>
```